# Reading from a .txt file and creating a nested dictionary python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I'm new to python and need some help regarding dictionaries.I have a text file

```
1;2;0.0008131  
1;714;0.0001097  
714;715;0.0016285  
715;796;0.0014631  
...
```

which represents source and destiantion nodes in a graph with the cost. I want to read the file and create a dictionary of the format

```
{'1': {'2': 0.0008131, '714': 0.0001097},
        '2': {'1': 0.0008131, '523': 0.0001097},
        '3': {'252': 0.0001052, '613':0.0002097},
```

and so on for every node with every adjacent node and cost between them.

Comment: Can you show your code attempt at this, please? Explain what is currently not working out for you. Show any error messages with the stack trace, if any.

Comment: Since 1 -> 2 is the same as 2 -> 1, you probably want a custom `__getitem__()` method that sorts the two numbers in ascending order and internally store the cost for only 1 -> 2.

Comment: I want the graph structure to be like an adjacency list with each key having every other adjacent node with its cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the following simple code should work for you.

```
# Open your text file
f = open('file.dat')

# Create empty dictionary 
graph = {}

for line in f:
    x = line.rstrip().split(";")
    if not x[0] in graph:
        graph[x[0]] = {x[1] : x[2]}
    else:
        graph[x[0]][x[1]] = x[2]

    if not x[1] in graph:
        graph[x[1]] = {x[0] : x[2]}
    else:
        graph[x[1]][x[0]] = x[2]

print(graph)
```

Where `graph` is the final dictionary that you want.

Comment: the cosole says  :
graph[x[0]] = {x[1] : x[2]}
"IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Does your file have 3 columns exactly in each row? If I use the few lines of text file that you provided at the start, my code gives me the desired output.

Comment: You were right, 1 line had a special character , fixed it. Thanx for the help but is there any way to remove the '\n' from the cost ?  im using this graph as an input for Dijkstra's shortest path calculation. Do I need to convert the 3rd column to integer type or something of that sort ?

Comment: `\n` shouldn't appear in cost. I guess in the first line in `for` loop, you didn't use`line.rstrip()`

Comment: Oh yes, and btw is there any typer conversion in python? because i want the 3rd coloumn items to be added as double

Comment: Yes. So `int(a)` would convert `a` into `int`. But in that case your cost values would be zero always! Also, please try searching google for such  simple questions yourself first. Cheers :)